# ActiveAdmin generating wrong routes for belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, belongs-to

I'm using *Rails 4.2.7.1* with *ActiveAdmin 1.0.0* and have the same resource being mentioned in two pages:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project
ActiveAdmin.register Project, as: "Awesome Project"
```

The first one generates routes as `admin/projects` and the latter as `admin/awesome_projects`.

The issue comes when I have a **belongs_to** association:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Task do
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I would expect the routes generated for task are `admin/projects/:project_id/tasks`. 
Somehow this is not entirely true in an indeterministic way.

In my development and staging environments the routes are generated as I stated above but in my production environment they are generated as `admin/awesome_projects/:awesome_project_id/tasks`...

Is there a way I can specify these routes in a deterministic way?